# WeakReference Bug?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

```
[TestMethod]
public void Memory()
{
    var wr = new WeakReference("aaabbb");
    Assert.IsTrue(wr.IsAlive);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.Collect();
    Assert.IsFalse(wr.IsAlive); //<-- fails here
}
```

It's .NET 3.5 SP1
Can anyone can tell me why this test fails?

**Edit**: Thanks stusmith

> You have a reference to a string,
>   which since it is a constant, is
>   probably interned (ie not dynamically
>   allocated), and will never be
>   collected.

That was it. Changed first line to

```
var wr = new WeakReference(new object());
```

and the test passes :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can think of two possible reasons off the top of my head:

1. You're running in debug. References in debug last longer than in release, and possibly longer than you might think.
2. You have a reference to a string, which since it is a constant, is probably interned (ie not dynamically allocated), and will never be collected.

Comment: you can actually verify the second one by changing the weak reference to this. var wr = new WeakReference(new Random().Next(50).ToString() ); You will then see the test pass