# Does WeakReference work with String?

Tags: .net, string, weak-references

In .NET 3.5, Does WeakReference work with String or shall I wrap it in a small "class" to make it work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.String` (`string` in C#) is a reference type, so there is no reason it should not work perfecctly well with [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx). Ignore the fact that it is in some ways a special reference type (immutable, for a start) - the CLR sees it as a reference type.

Saying this, [this other StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208387/weakreference-bug) makes a good point that string references can be 'interned' in many situations, and therefore the "expected" behaviour with regards to garbage collection is not observed.

Comment: That was my first thought, but is that true? See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208387/weakreference-bug

Comment: @Razzie: That's just an implication of how the GC happens to work with strings.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely work with WeakReference without any problems as System.String is a simple reference type.  It would be interesting to see your use case for using a WeakReference as it doesn't seem to fit the "normal" uses of WeakReference.

From the [MSDN Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247(VS.100).aspx):

Use long weak references only when necessary as the state of the object is unpredictable after finalization.

Avoid using weak references to small objects because the pointer itself may be as large or larger.

Avoid using weak references as an automatic solution to memory management problems. Instead, develop an effective caching policy for handling your application's objects.

Comment: My case is I've got so many strings, normally they are stored in DB and I only want to release them when I'm out of memory. Actually a better caching would be better, but I couldn't find any good way to release cache when memory is low.

Comment: I'd expect the garbage collector to work as expected and clean up references to strings (unless interned) as the app runs.  If you're not seeing these being collected, I guess you're either holding onto references or the strings are being interned.

Answer (score 0):

There generally isn't much point to using a weak reference to point to a deeply-immutable object, especially one which doesn't reference any other objects.  If the data is useful, you should hold a strong reference.  If it's not useful, you shouldn't hold any reference.  The use of WeakReference is only really appropriate in cases where the usefulness of the weakly-referenced object is contingent upon the existence of a strong reference; the most common such case is where a weak reference is used to put information into an object which will be read via strong reference.  If nobody's going to read the information put into the object, there's no reason for the writer to bother with it anymore.